# Apache 2 with Weblogic Plug-in Redirection, original location still requested to backend

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, weblogic

We're trying to setup an SSL server in front of a Weblogic server using Apache as the SSL provider. Here's what's inside of our httpd.conf:

```
<Location /original>
     SetHandler weblogic-handler
     WebLogicHost 10.11.1.1
     WebLogicPort 8700
     PathTrim /original
     PathPrepend /destination
     ConnectTimeoutSecs 60
</Location>

<Location /destination>
     SetHandler weblogic-handler
     WebLogicHost 10.11.1.1
     WebLogicPort 8700
     ConnectTimeoutSecs 60
</Location>
```

This setup works mostly, but in the ssl_error_log file there're these entries:

```
[Wed Aug 11 14:59:00 2010] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ap_proxy: trying GET /original at backend host '10.11.1.1/8700; got
     exception 'CONNECTION_REFUSED [os error=0, line 1739 of ../nsapi/URL.cpp]: Error connecting to host 10.11.1.1:8700'
```

The weird thing is, the redirection still works, but these annoying entries still shows up. Anyone can point out where did we go wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to tune weblogic with Accept Backlog

To tune the Accept Backlog value from the Administration Console:

1. Start the Administration Server if it is not already running.
2. Access the Administration Console for the domain.
3. Expand the Servers node in the left pane to display the servers configured 
   in your domain.
4. Click the name of the server instance that you want to configure.
5. Select the Configuration -> Tuning tab.
6. Modify the default Accept Backlog value as necessary to tune how many TCP  connections can be buffered in a wait queue:During operations, if many connections are dropped 
   or refused at the client, and no other error messages are on the server, the Accept Backlog value might be set too low.

If you are getting "connection refused" messages when you try to access  WebLogic Server, raise the Accept Backlog value from the default by 25 percent.

Continue increasing the value by 25 percent until the messages cease to appear.

Click Apply to save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing original path only because the backend wasnt available, check it in your weblogic access logs.

If your connections to weblogic are being backlogged you should see very high thread usage and this is what you have to solve, identifying the resource causing contention and either using less of this resource or increasing its availability.